# What's the best debugger for Akka development?

Tags: debugging, scala, ide, intellij-idea, akka

I am using Idea 10 with the scala plugin. Evaluating variables and adding watches for scala and akka variables is impossible. Have to resort to println. Is this any better on Eclipse ?

Comment: I've taken to PDD -- println driven development. :P

Comment: I try and factor my code so the actual work part of an actor is in its own class independent of Akka, then I can write specs tests and debug those in IntelliJ. As well as copious logging.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to use breakpoints and inspect members in the current eclipse plugin but it doesn't manage to hook successfully to source when stepping through lines of code nor have I been able to get expression evaluation (watches) to work.  There may be a trick to that I've missed though.